# Nextjs - Unexpected token "export"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, node-modules

I started with NextJS, before that I used React a lot.
I run the app on docker (node:18-alpine) if it makes any difference.

I have API thing that I wrote before and published as NPM module. Now I install it with `yarn add sjiamnocna/renette-api`, it's ok, I can use it with react.

I have file "next-app/utils/API/initapi.ts" containing

```
   import CAPI from "renette-api"
   const API = new CAPI()

   API.authenticateWithName('abcdef')
   API.authorizeWithKey('12345')

   export default API
```

It gives me `SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'`

Nothing I found worked so far, any idea?

---

EDIT1:
Suppose it fails during the runtime (running `yarn dev`) because it's successfully built and served for development. The CMD tells the same thing as the browser

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1026:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1151:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.renette-api (/home/sjiamnocna/Documents/wrk/docker_test/nginxphppg/next-app/.next/server/pages/index.js:52:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/sjiamnocna/Documents/wrk/docker_test/nginxphppg/next-app/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:33:42) {
  page: '/'
}
```

[image: Error in the browser, shortened]

I have the file in directory next to the `pages` directory, couldn't that cause anything?

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCCCAFAktA3gWAFDWmArgC4AWApgHaECWwYhpA6lSQHJgC2p0AFAB4Bc0CIQBOVcgHMAlIIBuAeyoATdNmy4AvurxFi8sQC9GzYgGlSATz6DhYyTOgLlqrNq1Z32YPPLDoSVABeaHJSAHc4AO4pNSwAgDoCEgpqWnomVg5SbgByMAAjYCVSADMcmLiURN19KiMMs0tcgEYAJgBmABYAVnLY0l4AB31CaGKSghBRgOwgA). Also, Typescript doesn't run at runtime, so what's compiling your code, and what does the compiled code look like? When are you seeing the error (i.e. compile time or runtime)?

Comment: I found the error doesn't appear if I do the import inside `pages` directory, so that might be the next hint, so I'll go google. Thanks so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the solution is "workaround".
I changed the target of my package to ES5, now it exports the old style as NextJS expects it. BUT, if you guys have some trick to make the ES6 imports work, tell me

```
// before
export default MyClass
// now
module.exports = default
```

Have a nice day